# How does a simple elliptic integral solve this monster?

Tags: integration, contour-integration, elliptic-integrals

During some electromagnetics calculation regarding a loop antenna I stumbled across the following integral

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\phi}{\big(1+\frac{k}{k-2}\cos(2\phi)\big)^{3/2}}$$

and Mathematica gave me the solution

$$\frac{(1-\frac{k}{2})^{3/2}}{k-1} E\left( k \right)$$

where $E(k)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind. Cool so far. Now I am not interested in the full solution process, but the following bothers me: When I write the above slightly differently and use the definition of $E(k)$, I get

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-k\sin^2(\phi)}d\phi = \frac{k-1}{(1-\frac{k}{2})^{3/2}} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\big(1+\frac{k}{k-2}\cos(2\phi)\big)^3}}d\phi$$

which totally overstrain or even contradicts my calculus intuition. I am wondering how on earth the simple elliptic integral on the LHS is able to account for all the intricacies of the involved, tedious monster with a third-order polynomial of cosines in the denominator of a square root on the RHS. Is there any concise argument that explains how $E(k)$ pulls off such a feat? If someone with a lot of experience in advanced integration could shed some light on this matter and give me some intuition, that'd be great.

Comment: The theory of elliptic integrals is very well developed. Any integral that can be written as a rational function time a square-root of a polynomial of maximal 4th degree can be solved in terms of them.

Comment: It should take you at least some of the way to use $\cos 2\phi=1-2\sin^2\phi$ to rewrite $$1+\frac{k}{k-2}\cos(2\phi)=\frac{1}{1-\frac k2}(1-k\sin^2\phi) $$

Comment: @HenningMakholm. I am probably stupid, but when I apply your good suggestion, what I get is $$1+\frac{k}{k-2}\cos(2\phi)=\frac{2 (k-1) \left(1-\frac{k \sin ^2(\phi )}{k-1}\right)}{k-2}$$

Comment: @Claude: You just need more routine algebra to simplify the right-hand side fraction. Unfortunately it turns out I dropped a term on the floor on the way to my result, where I rewrote $k(1-\sin^2\phi)$ to $k\sin^2\phi$ at one place. Fortunately $1-\sin^\phi$ is actually the same as $\cos^2\phi$, and since that's the only place $\phi$ appears we can substitute $\theta=\frac\pi2-\phi$ to make it into $\sin^2\theta$ instead -- except the first thing Jack D'Aurizio does in his solution is to _undo_ that substitution, so just leave it as $(1-k\cos^2\phi)/(1-\frac k2)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. So, I rephrase what I wrote :"I am probably stupid" **must** read "I am stupid". Thanks for the comment. Cheers :-(

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: It's not that bad. What you need to do from where you got to is just $$(k-1)(1-\frac{k\sin^2\phi}{k-1})  = (k-1)-k\sin^2\phi=k(1-\sin^2\phi)-1=k\cos^2\phi-1$$ and then divide by $-2$ above and below the remaining fraction bar to conclude $$1+\frac{k}{k-2}\cos(2\phi)=\frac{1-k\cos^2\phi}{1-\frac k2}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the Hanning Makholm's suggestion, we have
$$ I = \left(1-\frac{k}{2}\right)^{3/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(1-k\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}},\tag{1}$$
on the other hand:
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(1-k\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}}&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(1-k\cos^2\theta)^{3/2}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1+t^2)^{1/2}}{((1-k)+t^2)^{3/2}}\,dt\\&=&\frac{1}{1-k}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1+(1-k)u^2)^{1/2}}{(1+u^2)^{3/2}}\,du\\&=&\frac{1}{1-k}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos^2\theta+(1-k)\sin^2\theta\right)^{1/2}\,d\theta\\&=&\frac{1}{1-k}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-k\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta = \color{red}{\frac{E(k)}{1-k}}. \end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Actually I now believe that if I had done my algebra right it should have been $\frac{1}{1-\frac k2}(1-k\cos^2\phi)$, so your first substitution isn't even necessary.